# Bash Script: Find and Remove Folders Older Than 7 Days, With File That Does NOT Contain a Certain String

Tags: string, bash, find

I need to come up with a Bash script that will remove any folders within a directory if they meet both of the following criteria:

1. Older than 7 days.
2. Have an xml file in them that does not contain a certain string.

I know that this command works for removing all folders in the directory that are older than *n* days:

```
find ./ -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {}\;
```

And this command removes all of the files named kittens.xml that don't have the string `<claws>18</claws>`:

```
find ./* -name "kittens.xml" -type f\! -exec grep -L "<claws>18</claws>" {} \;| xargs rm -fv
```

But how do I remove all the folders that are more than one week old and *don't* contain that string?

FYI, I have very little prior experience with Bash.

Comment: One command operates on directories, the other on files. Do you mean that you want to remove directories that are older than 7 days and don't contain any file that contains the string `<claws>18</claws>`?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in `find /WHERE/ARE/THOSE/DIRS -type d -mtime +7 2>/dev/null` ; do
  fgrep '<claws>18</claws>' "${dir}/kittens.xml" &>/dev/null || rm -fv "${dir}"
done
```

It loops through the found directories, then checks via fgrep for the needed string in the file, and if it's not found (e.g. not in the file OR the file is missing), removes the dir.

Note: it might cause damage, so think before run it. I'd run it first like this so it shows what it would remove...

```
  fgrep '<claws>18</claws>' "${dir}/kittens.xml" &>/dev/null || echo "rm -fv ${dir}"
```

Also if there are subdirs, it might cause problems.

Comment: This isn't working. When I execute this command, all I get is a ">", as if bash is waiting for some other input. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the grep `v` or `--invert-match` tags:

```
find ./* -name "kittens.xml" -type f\! -exec grep -L -v "<claws>18</claws>" {} \;| xargs rm -fv
```

You can find more about *grep invert* by using this in terminal:

```
grep --help | grep invert
```